# Single item that offers the most cooldown reduction

Tags: league-of-legends

Which single item offers the highest amount of cooldown reduction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of today, 3 items give the most cooldown reduction, which is 20%:

- [Nashor's Tooth](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/item/nashors-tooth-84) [image: nashor's tooth icon]

> 65 Ability Power, 50 Attack Speed, 10 Mana Regeneration. **UNIQUE Passive: +20% Cooldown Reduction.**

- [Morellonomicon](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/item/morellonomicon-156) [image: Morellonomicon icon]

  > 75 Ability Power, **+20% Cooldown Reduction**, 12 Mana Regeneration. UNIQUE
  >   Passive: Dealing magic damage to an enemy champion below 40% health
  >   inflicts Grievous Wounds on them for 4 seconds. (Grievous wounds
  >   reduces healing and regeneration rates by 50%)
- [Frozen Heart](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/item/frozen-heart-81) [image: Frozen Heart icon]

  > 90 Armor, **+20% Cooldown Reduction**, 400 Mana. UNIQUE Passive: Reduces the
  >   attack speed of nearby enemies by 20% (1000 range).

Comment: after looking at the 3,i can narrow out that nashors tooth has the highest cooldown reduction which is 25%.But otherwise,thank you for showing me the possible answers

Comment: @thatguy im pretty sure Nashor's has 20% as well. but I agree with Gnoupi.

Comment: @thatguy cdr stacks up until 40% which is the maximum you can get (cap)

Comment: oh.. maybe the site has given the wrong stat :/      http://leaguepedia.com/wiki/Nashor%27s_Tooth

Comment: @thatguy it used to be 25% thats why its just not updated yet. ;)

Comment: 20% of 0 is 0. 20 of 0 is 20. 20% of 20 is 4. **So, it's not 20% but 20**

Comment: @Michel - it's *adding* to the percentage of cooldown reduction

Comment: @Gnoupi - Ahh, ok =) I tough was only the number (don't play in a while LOL, sorry)

Comment: As of patch 3.02, Athene's Unholy Grail, Spirit Visage, and Zeke's Herald also have 20% CDR.